# I'm stuck on “Choose Startup Disk”

Tags: mac, disk-utility, startup, restart

During restart I am stuck at `Choose Startup Disk`. There is no option showing on the display. I am waiting for 20 mins and nothing shows up. Here what I see

[image: Stuck on Choose Startup Disk]

How long I should wait? Or there is something I should do? Any solution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to solve it:

1. Shutdown the Mac.
2. Press the button to turn on and hold it until it opens the Options.
3. Once that's loaded, I got a screen similar to the following

   [image: Not stuck anymore]
4. Clicked in `Reinstall macOS Monterey` and just followed the wizard.

   [image: Problem solved]

*Note*: In step 4 I've also connected to Wi-Fi in the top right.